# How to leave one active button in the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, expression

I am beginner.
I have four buttons and I want to leave one active button every time with expression operator (if). One button must have active every time .
I tried to do it something like that. I am open to your ideas, if you can do without (if) .Help me!

```js
var count = 4;
var flag = true;

function select(currentColor, changeColor){
    if(count > 1 && flag === true){
        var currentElement = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName(currentColor));
        currentElement.toggleClass(changeColor);
        count--;
        console.log(count);
        console.log('From minus: ' + count);
    }else{
        flag = false;
    }

    if(count < 4 && flag === false) {
        var currentElement = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName(currentColor));
        currentElement.toggleClass(changeColor);
        count++;
        console.log(count);
        console.log('From plus: ' + count);
    }else{
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .changeColor{
            color: red !important;
        }

        .first{
            color: #07888A;
        }

        .second{
            color: #07888A;
        }

        .third{
            color: #07888A;
        }

        .fourth{
            color: #07888A;
        }
      
      h1{
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<h1 class="first" onClick="select('first', 'changeColor')">First</h1>
<h1 class="second" onClick="select('second', 'changeColor')">Second</h1>
<h1 class="third" onClick="select('third', 'changeColor')">Third</h1>
<h1 class="fourth" onClick="select('fourth', 'changeColor')">Fourth</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this bit:

```
function select(currentColor, changeColor) {
  // Get the list of the `.changeColor` elements.
  changed = document.querySelectorAll(".changeColor");
  // Loop through all the elements with `changeColor` class.
  for (i = 0; i < changed.length; i++)
    // Remove the changeColor class from their class list.
    changed[i].classList.remove("changeColor");

  // Rest comes your code.
  if(count > 1 && flag === true){
```

Comment: Can you write what do you mean?

Comment: @Djo I don't understand. Do you want me to explain the code?

Comment: Hmm..
I am sorry, I mean that user may chose three buttons and one button must be disable when user choice three buttons

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to get one button disabled when any three buttons are enabled ? if so, perhaps this could help. I highly suggest not to use the h1 tags for this purpose, and use something like a button or div, and removing the onclick attributes from your elements and incorporate them in your main js file similar to the js snippet found below.

```
(function() {
    //an empty array to track the number of elements currently colored
    var numberOfElesColored = [],
        eles = document.querySelectorAll('h1'),
        //the number of active elements allowed at once
        numberOfActiveElementsAllowed = eles.length - 1;


    //loop though all the elements and attach click event
    [].forEach.call(eles, function(ele, i) {

        ele.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

            var currentEle = event.target;


            //is there at least two other elements avaliable still ?
            if (!(numberOfElesColored.length === numberOfActiveElementsAllowed)) {
                //yes
                //is the current clicked element not active already ?
                if (!currentEle.classList.contains('changeColor')) {
                    //yes 

                    //add 1 to tracking array 
                    numberOfElesColored.push(1);
                    //activate element
                    return currentEle.classList.add('changeColor');
                } else {
                    //no

                    //remove 1 from tracking array
                    numberOfElesColored.pop();
                    //deactivate elements
                    return currentEle.classList.remove('changeColor');
                }

                //are all the elements active already ?
            } else if (numberOfElesColored.length === numberOfActiveElementsAllowed) {
                //yes 
                //is the current element an active one ?
                if (currentEle.classList.contains('changeColor')) {
                    //yes 
                    //remove 1 from tracking array
                    numberOfElesColored.pop();
                    //deactivate element
                    return currentEle.classList.remove('changeColor');
                }

            }



        });

    });


})();
```